# Transactions in Redis - Read operations in another database

Tags: redis, transactions

We are trying to implement caching for our multi-tenant application. We are planning to create new Redis DB for each tenant.

We have one scenario where we need to use Redis Transactions. While going through this post https://redis.io/topics/transactions, we found that

> All the commands in a transaction are serialized and executed
>   sequentially. It can never happen that a request issued by another
>   client is served in the middle of the execution of a Redis
>   transaction. This guarantees that the commands are executed as a
>   single isolated operation.

Is this read blocking will only apply to database level or at full instance level?

Answer (score 1):

The guarantee you quoted applies to the instance, not the database. A command for DB 2 will not run in the middle of a transaction for DB 1.

You can find more information about multiple databases (including an argument by the creator of Redis against using them at all) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221563/whats-the-point-of-multiple-redis-databases).