# redis multi dbs vs single db, which one is best?

Tags: redis

i have two plan for my redis key , one for separate several db ,one for each project ,another is put the keys on a whole big db, use the key name prefix to distinct them like " db1:xxx ,db2:xxx ",which one is better ? why?

Answer (score 1):

Please reference to this post: [What's the Point of Multiple Redis Databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221563/whats-the-point-of-multiple-redis-databases)

In my opinion, it's not good to use multiple databases in a single redis instance, as Salvatore(Author of Redis) said here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/redis-db/vS5wX8X4Cjg/8ounBXitG4sJ

But if just for development, both of your choice are ok.