# Configuring Redis as Cache interface in a Laravel 5 Application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, caching, redis

I have a **Laravel** application that I am integrating a **Redis Server** into to handle the application caching. However I am having issues with the Redis configuration, as I am not able to access the **Redis** interface using the **Laravel** cache facade.

I set up a redis-server and comfirmed that it is working on the server:

```
> redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379 > ping
PONG
```

I then followed the integration documentation for Redis/Laravel from here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redis

I installed the composer predis/predis package...
I set it up in Laravel to use the default redis config:

**app/config/cache.php:**

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'redis'),
```

**app/config/database.php:**

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
    ],
]
```

**.env:**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

---

Now when I test I can access **Redis** via the **Redis Facade**...

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

...but not from the **Cache Facade**.

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

```
    // ************* this works
    Redis::set('testFromRedisSet', 'RedisSet');

    // ************* none of these work...
    Cache::store('redis')->put('testFromStoreCachePut', 'CacheStorePut', 600);

    Cache::put('testFromCachePut', 'CachePut', 600);

    Cache::remember('testFromCacheRemember', 60, function() {
       return "CacheRemember";
    });
    Cache::rememberForever('testFromCacheRememberForever', function() {
        return "CacheRememberForever";
    });
```

> 127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS '*'
>   1) "testFromRedisSet"
>   127.0.0.1:6379>

---

Interestingly enough the Cache Facade still appears to be functioning properly. If I monitor the cache requests in **Telescope**, the 4 cache requests in the example that are not showing up in the **Redis Server** are still being cached somewhere, and using the Cache facade to retrieve these 4 values works fine.

...all these retrieve the correct values:

```
Cache::get('testFromCacheStoreRedisPut');
Cache::get('testFromCachePut');
Cache::get('testFromCacheRemember');
Cache::get('testFromCacheRememberForever');
```

---

**So what is going on here?**

It looks like Laravel is utilizing the [redis] cache driver correctly, because when I shut down the **Redis Server** and retest the app the entire applications throws a **Predis Connection Exception**:

> In AbstractConnection.php line 155: Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

**Where are the cache keys being stored and why can't I view the stored keys  in the terminal using "redis-cli"?**

> redis-cli KEYS '*'

Monitoring the `Redis Server` shows me that `Redis` is storing the data and pushing event notifications, but all data that I can't see in the termimal is prefixed with `laravel_cache`. However there is no data or hash key with that name present in the interface.

```
1561596707.950397 [1 127.0.0.1:42058] "SETEX" "laravel_cache:testFromCacheStoreRedisPut" "36000" "s:18:\"CacheStoreRedisPut\";"
1561596707.950898 [1 127.0.0.1:42058] "SETEX" "laravel_cache:testFromCachePut" "36000" "s:8:\"CachePut\";"
1561596707.951521 [1 127.0.0.1:42058] "GET" "laravel_cache:testFromCacheRemember"
1561596707.952110 [1 127.0.0.1:42058] "GET" "laravel_cache:testFromCacheRememberForever"
1561596707.952718 [1 127.0.0.1:42058] "GET" "laravel_cache:testFromCacheStoreRedisPut"
1561596707.953236 [1 127.0.0.1:42058] "GET" "laravel_cache:testFromCachePut"
1561596707.953745 [1 127.0.0.1:42058] "GET" "laravel_cache:testFromCacheRemember"
1561596707.954191 [1 127.0.0.1:42058] "GET" "laravel_cache:testFromCacheRememberForever"
1561596709.251036 [0 127.0.0.1:42064] "SELECT" "1"
1561596709.251200 [1 127.0.0.1:42064] "GET" "laravel_cache:telescope:dump-watcher"
1561596709.263678 [1 127.0.0.1:42064] "GET" "laravel_cache:telescope:pause-recording"
```

**How can i accesss the data being stored in the `laravel_cache` namespace? Even running the same `GET` commands shown in the server monitor does not fetch any data directly.**

Comment: What does your `.env` look like? The `CACHE_DRIVER` in the example is set to `file`, so if you copied the `.env.example` then it's set to use the wrong driver.

Comment: It isn't the .env file. I updated 'CACHE_DRIVER' in there also... I just added the contents of .env to the question info.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Redis cache store](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.7/config/cache.php#L75) uses the `cache` database connection by default. If you look at [config/database.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.7/config/database.php#L126) it switches to database `1` for caching by default. To view the keys in the terminal, you have to `select` which database to use first.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SELECT 1
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> KEYS *
```

Using different databases allows you to separate your cache and session store, it can be handy when you need to delete all cache keys (`flushdb`) but keep the user session. You can even add a separate connection for queues. Note that [it's not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16221563) to use multiple databases, use multiple Redis instance instead.

Comment: This just solved my problem as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> As mentioned in the comments, Correctly setting the default would be a better solution than explicitly defining the store

You need to specify the store:

`Cache::store('redis')->put('bar', 'baz', 600); // 10 Minutes`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache#cache-usage

Comment: Correctly setting the default would be a better solution. The only time you should explicitly define the store is when you need to use a different store for different parts of the application.

Comment: Explicitly defining the store has the same effect as setting up the default. Neither work.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution!**

In `config\database.php` UPDATE the value of `default` & `cache` with `1`

```
'redis' => [

    'default' => [

         // Other settings...

        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 1),
    ],

    'cache' => [

         // Other settings...

        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
    ],

],
```