# what does the numerical database value in redis setting do?

Tags: redis, magento2

Below redis settings for a magento 2 site. what does the numerical database value 0 or 1 stand for and how does this impact the site performance? What should be the correct value? Appreciate assistance on this please.

```
'session' => [
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => [
            'host' => '/var/run/redis/redis.sock',
            'port' => '0',
            'password' => '',
            'timeout' => '2.5',
            'persistent_identifier' => '',
            'database' => '0',
            'compression_threshold' => '2048',
            'compression_library' => 'gzip',
            'log_level' => '1',
            'max_concurrency' => '6',
            'break_after_frontend' => '5',
            'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
            'first_lifetime' => '600',
            'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
            'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
            'disable_locking' => '0',
            'min_lifetime' => '60',
            'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
        ]

'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => '/var/run/redis/redis.sock',
                    'database' => '1',
                    'port' => '0',
                    'compression_threshold' => '2048',
                    'compression_library' => 'gzip',
                    'log_level' => '1',
                    'max_concurrency' => '6',
                    'break_after_frontend' => '5',
                    'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
                    'first_lifetime' => '600',
                    'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
                    'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
                    'disable_locking' => '0',
                    'min_lifetime' => '60',
                    'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: See [the documentation](https://redis.io/commands/select) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221563/whats-the-point-of-multiple-redis-databases).

Comment: The Redis database that they are stored in...