# Redis 6 Multithreading and multiple Redis databases

Tags: redis

I'm trying to get more familiar with Redis, and I found that the [Redis 6 release notes](https://redislabs.com/blog/diving-into-redis-6/) say the following:

> Redis 6 rings in a new era: while it retains a core single-threaded data-access interface, I/O is now threaded.

This multithreading seems particularly useful for writes, as mentioned in the [redis.conf](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/bdd541174736522c92ff786576e744269c3a1c2c/redis.conf#L972)

Multiple databases in Redis has been discussed several times, like at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221563/whats-the-point-of-multiple-redis-databases/16243787#16243787) and [Redis DB google group](https://groups.google.com/g/redis-db/c/vS5wX8X4Cjg/m/8ounBXitG4sJ). The StackOverflow answer says the following:

> It is deprecated and, as you noted, multiple instances lets you take advantage of multiple cores.

Because the Redis 6 release notes say "a core single-threaded data-access interface" is retained - does this mean multiple instances of Redis will still take better advantage of multiple cores for data accessing than multiple Redis databases on a single Redis instance will?

Does retaining "a core single-threaded data-access interface" mean that all data-access commands (like GET, SET), regardless of which database in the redis instances, will have to go through this interface (rather than multiple data-access interfaces if we used multiple Redis instances instead) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because the Redis 6 release notes say "a core single-threaded data-access interface" is retained - does this mean multiple instances of Redis will still take better advantage of multiple cores for data accessing than multiple Redis databases on a single Redis instance will?

Yes, multiple instances of Redis will probably have have better utilization of a multi-core server.

> Does retaining "a core single-threaded data-access interface" mean that all data-access commands (like GET, SET), regardless of which database in the redis instances, will have to go through this interface (rather than multiple data-access interfaces if we used multiple Redis instances instead) ?

Yes, Redis 6 maintains this property.